# Trying to install Ruby but getting Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

mugo@mugo-ThinkPad-X240:~$ rvm install 2.7.4 --default
ruby-2.7.4 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.4..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.4 - #downloading ruby-2.7.4, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.4 - #extracting ruby-2.7.4 to /usr/share/rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4.....
ruby-2.7.4 - #configuring........................................................................
ruby-2.7.4 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.7.4 - #compiling..........................................|
..............................................................................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1668239441_ruby-2.7.4/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

I am trying to install Ruby 2.7.4 and I expected Ruby to download after using the command rvm install 2.7.4 --default but in vain.

Comment: update your rvm using **rvm get head** and then try again.